# import python modules and access to MQTT ports

Tags: mqtt, paho, pythonanywhere

In pythonanywhere Can import the modules listed below and access to the MQTT TCP/IP ports 8883 and 1883?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import ssl
import json
import binascii
#
import time
import thingspeak
import random
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the modules you need. As for access to MQTT ports: You cannot connect out of PythonAnywhere on MQTT ports from a free account, but you can from a paid account. You cannot run an MQTT server on PythonAnywhere, either.